# Website not Working in Nokia Lumia

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, windows-phone

My website works in android and IOS browsers, but its not opening up in Nokia Lumia IE Browser.It throws the following,

[image]

When I searched for an app using its suggestion nothing showed up. I tried with other similar websites and they worked fine. Don't know whats causing this problem. Its a nodejs website built with bootstrap 3.1.1 framework. Does anyone have any idea what's causing this.

Thanks In Advance....

Comment: is it configured to access web? maybe time/date of phone are out of sync

Comment: @GeoPhoenix But Other similar sites work. Why not this......

Comment: does nodejs even gets the request?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix don't know i will check an see

Comment: @GeoPhoenix no the log show no sign of request, when accessed by the device

Comment: then it must be a problem with the device, since nodejs is accessed properly from other devices/media.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Thanks. I will see to it. But other sites work. Don't know how

Comment: Do have IE11 installed on Windows? Go to the Emulation tab of the F12 Dev Tools and try accessing your site with the Windows Phone browser profile. Then you can inspect the sent/received data in the network tab. If there's no issue, something is wrong on your device. Unfortunately, accessing mdesk.co gives me a DNS error, so I guess it is not for public and I can't check it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. Its due to the content type in the node js configuration. It works fine after changing it.